# How do I fix stop "Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool" error code in c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a console app for an assignment and I keep getting the "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

```
            Console.WriteLine("Get ready for a *MATH SHOWDOWN*");

            Console.Write("If you would like a tutorial on how this works say \"tutorial\", If you would like to go ahead and start say \"start\"");
            int openingprompt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (openingprompt = '1') 
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for equality (==) not assign (=)

```
Console.WriteLine("Get ready for a *MATH SHOWDOWN*");

Console.Write("If you would like a tutorial on how this works say \"tutorial\", If you would like to go ahead and start say \"start\"");
int openingprompt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (openingprompt == '1') 
{

}
```